# Inserting a New Column into a CSV File

Tags: csv, awk

I need to insert a new column in front of the first column in a CSV file. I'm trying to use an `awk` solution

**CSV File**

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7,8
4,5,6,7,8,9
```

**Attempted Code**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$1=$1 OFS (FNR<1 ? $1 "0\n0\n0\n0" : "col")}1'
```

**Expected Result**

```
col,A,B,C,D,E,F
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
0,2,3,4,5,6,7
0,3,4,5,6,7,8
0,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Comment: Is first column always `0` which you want to have? Please confirm once.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying! The first column may not always be a 0.

Comment: Ok, you mean you want to add values apart from 0 also? If yes then kindly explain logic of adding them, thank you

Comment: Be warned that `FNR<1` is always false as rows are numbered starting from 1.

Comment: Yes, the values may be different from 0, i.e. data from a data stream.

Comment: I rolled back your edit since the answers wouldn't make sense otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.csv` content be

```
A,B,C,D,E,F
1,2,3,4,5,6
2,3,4,5,6,7
3,4,5,6,7,8
4,5,6,7,8,9
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{print NR==1?"col":"0", $0}' file.csv
```

gives output

```
col,A,B,C,D,E,F
0,1,2,3,4,5,6
0,2,3,4,5,6,7
0,3,4,5,6,7,8
0,4,5,6,7,8,9
```

Explanation: I inform GNU `AWK` that both field separator and output field separator is comma. For each line I print `col` if it is first row else `0` followed by whole line (`$0`).

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: I think that nice solution works in Posix awk too.

Answer (score 1):

One way could be to print `col,` if it's the first line and `0,` if it's any of the other lines. Then print the rest of the columns:

```
awk 'NR==1 { printf("col,") } NR>1 { printf("0,") } { print }'
```

Broken down:

```
NR==1 {             # execute this block if it's the first line
    printf("col,")
}
NR>1 {              # execute this block if it's any other line
    printf("0,")
}
{                   # always execute this block
    print
}
```